# Why in SE's relevant sites the live-refresh of newly asked questions not working?

Tags: discussion, support, live-refresh

So here is the flow I followed. Click Questions button on top of Stack Overflow / Super User site and clicked [newest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?sort=newest&pagesize=50) tab. Then I got newest questions and keeping this window idle for some time, I got notification on the window title with count of newly posted questions. So, here Auto-refresh is working. But from last week, what I have observed is Auto-refresh is not working. I have to manually click newest tab? Why auto-refresh not working?

Comment: Funny that, because it's just *started* working for me here - previously the proxy was blocking the requests.

Comment: I just verified StackOverflow based on your comment, but still live-refresh is not working

Comment: Do you have firebug or something like that installed? Or something that can show you network errors? That's probably the best thing to check.

Comment: ok thanks but is that individual machine problem??

Comment: It might be, or network, or anything between you and Stack Exchange.

Comment: ok but lets hope for the best solution will be provided here based on "Is this the bug?" or "Network Error". If it is a network error, displaying error dialog is a good way of live-refresh implementation that i think...

Comment: Wasn't the feature disabled on Stack Overflow (at least the main page)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution while checking `live-refresh` functionality in multiple web browsers and that its the browser issue. While i am checking in `Google Chrome`(verified for `StackOverflow` and `SuperUser`), the `live-refresh` is not working but in `Mozilla Firefox` it is working fine. So, Browser compatibility is missing for `live-refresh`.

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding, live refresh works just fine in Chrome. Google chrome is my default browser, and I have never had an issue with the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Super User, but last time I knew Stackoverflow's auto-refresh was disabled for the "Newest" tab because of the amount of questions that are posted daily.

However, the feature works as expected if you are only looking at specific tags.